# How to get the column id value from table in entityframework

Tags: entity-framework-4

Is there a way to get the column id value using Entity Framework 4?

The same like this SQL Query:

```
Select Orderid from OrderItems where Orderid  = 1;
```

Comment: why u don't use Link..?

Answer (score 0):

You can get the key values of entities by querying `EntityKey`s from the `ObjectStateManger`. In EF4 (assuming you have an `ObjectContext`) it goes like this:

```cs
foreach (var ek in context.ObjectStateManager
            .GetObjectStateEntries(System.Data.EntityState.Unchanged)
            .Select(objectStateEntry => objectStateEntry.EntityKey))
{
    System.Data.EntityKeyMember[] keys = ek.EntityKeyValues;
    // Do something with keys
}
```

In EF6 (with `DbContext`) it's done like so:

```cs
var oc = ((IObjectContextAdapter)context).ObjectContext;
foreach (var ek in oc.ObjectStateManager
            .GetObjectStateEntries(System.Data.Entity.EntityState.Unchanged)
            .Select(objectStateEntry => objectStateEntry.EntityKey))
{
    System.Data.Entity.Core.EntityKeyMember[] keys = ek.EntityKeyValues;
    // Do something with keys
}
```

This will get the key values of entities that have been loaded into the context at this point.